# Hyperbolic three-manifolds that fiber over the circle

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, mapping-class-groups

Let $f$ be a pseudo-Anosov mapping class of a closed, connected, and oriented genus $g > 1$ surface. Let $M(f)$ be the corresponding hyperbolic three-dimensional mapping torus of $f$. Is the length of homotopically non-trivial loops in $M(f)$ bounded below in terms of the genus $g$ of the fiber?

A comment to this question [Hyperbolic 3-manifolds fibering over the circle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151892/hyperbolic-3-manifolds-fibering-over-the-circle) suggests that this is the case. Any details and references are highly welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Question:** Is the length of homotopically non-trivial loops in $M(f)$ bounded below in terms of the genus $g$ of the fiber?

**Answer:** No. Here is one family of examples.  Suppose that $S$ is the closed oriented surface of genus two.  Suppose that $\alpha$ is an essential curve in $S$.  Let $T_\alpha$ be the left Dehn twist about $\alpha$.  Suppose that $g \colon S \to S$ is a pseudo-Anosov map.  Define $f_n = g T_\alpha^n$, for any integer $n$.  Fathi proves that $f_n$ is again pseudo-Anosov (for all but at most seven consecutive values of $n$.)  The Minsky "machine" (namely the proof of the ending lamination conjecture, due to Minsky and Brock-Canary-Minsky) shows that the injectivity radius of $M(f_n)$ tends to zero as $n$ tends to $\pm \infty$.

---

Note that, in the above examples, the "shrinking curve" in $M(f_n)$ does not "go around" the bundle: that is, its image in $\mathbb{Z} \cong \pi_1(S^1)$ is trivial.  Your question has a positive answer if we avoid such curves.

**Sketch proof**: (without actual estimates, of the contrapositive.) Suppose that $\gamma$ is a very short curve in $M(f)$ with non-trivial image in $\pi_1(S^1)$.  We must bound the genus of the fibre, $S$, from below.  So, isotope $S$ to be a minimal surface. The thick-thin decomposition tells us that there is a large radius embedded tube $N(\gamma)$ about $\gamma$.  The fibre $S$ must cross $N(\gamma)$.  Thus $S$ has large area and so, because it is minimal, it has large genus. $\Box$

To give the details (and so find actual estimates) you need to understand the geometry of Margulis tubes in hyperbolic three-dimensional manifolds.